# MySQL Procedure won't do anything

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

This stored procedure should insert an entry after a `SELECT` for a foreign key. Currently, It does nothing. When I `CALL` it, it won't give me an error or anything and won't insert the record either.

Can I even do multiple things (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT..) in a single procedure? If yes, what am I missing here? If there is an error while running one of the (update/insert/select)s, should I get an error?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `InserAndAttachReferencia` (
                IN refereciaText VARCHAR(45),
                IN attachTo INT unsigned,
                OUT insid INT unsigned
            )
BEGIN
    -- SELECT THE REP_ID 
    DECLARE attachToRepID INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT id
    INTO attachToRepID
    FROM AlkReferencia
    WHERE id=attachTo;
    -- INSERTING THE NEW ENTRY WITH GIVEN REP_ID
    INSERT INTO AlkReferencia (id,rep_id,csatolva_id,referencia)
    VALUES(null,attachToRepID,attachTo,referenciaText);
    SET insid = LAST_INSERT_ID();   
END
```

Edit.:
Yeah, the last update is useless here, should just set the rep_id while inserting, but it is not the issue here. (Copied from one of my other procedure, when I need the last update...)..Fixed in the question.

Table:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `AlkatreszDb`.`AlkReferencia`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `AlkatreszDb`.`AlkReferencia` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AlkatreszDb`.`AlkReferencia` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rep_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `csatolva_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `referencia` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_AlkReferencia_AlkReferencia1_idx` (`rep_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_AlkReferencia_AlkReferencia2_idx` (`csatolva_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_AlkReferencia_AlkReferencia1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`rep_id`)
    REFERENCES `AlkatreszDb`.`AlkReferencia` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_AlkReferencia_AlkReferencia2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`csatolva_id`)
    REFERENCES `AlkatreszDb`.`AlkReferencia` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Edit the question and include the definition of the table.  Perhaps the `insert` is failing because of a constraint violation.  Do you have any triggers on the table?

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to fix your problem, but you can simplify the code to:

```
INSERT INTO AlkReferencia(rep_id, csatolva_id, referencia)
    SELECT ar.id, attachTo, referenciaText
    FROM AlkReferencia ar
    WHERE ar.id = attachTo;
```

I would also prepend the variable names with `v_` (or something) to distinguish them from column names.  That is often a source of errors in stored procedures:

```
INSERT INTO AlkReferencia(rep_id, csatolva_id, referencia)
    SELECT ar.id, v_attachTo, v_referenciaText
    FROM AlkReferencia ar
    WHERE ar.id = v_attachTo;
```

EDIT:

This code is quite suspicious:

```
SELECT id
INTO attachToRepID
FROM AlkReferencia
WHERE id = attachTo;
```

Why not just use `attachTo`?  Do you intend for one of the references to really be `csatolva_id`?

Comment: Yes, SELECT rep_id instead of SELECT id. True. But still the procedure does nothing :(

Comment: In theory, can I use multiple update/insert/delete statements in one procedure?

Comment: I found out what the problems is. The insert is aborted because of the foreign key constraints. Still don't know how to solve it though.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your code is outputting nothing.  Have you tried EXEC the procedure with parameters?